# what is meant by Orientation of a 3d vector in Cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: opengl, vector, geometry, kinect, rotational-matrices

So I am working on a project that has to obtain body joint angles with Kinect skeletal data(Microsoft SDK). I have 3d points in the camera coordinate system, I need to get the angles that one bone makes with a coordinate system fitted at the parent joint of that bone. For example, Left Knee and Left Ankle make a bone, say I fit a coordinate system at Left Knee with Z axis facing camera and Y axis going toward the preceding bone vector(i.e. Hip Center and Hip Left). How do I reach the coordinate system from the central Hip joint?

I read somewhere that I can sequentially multiply the "Orientation" of the Hip joint and then the Orientation of the Hip Left and next the orientation of the Left Knee joint to fit the coordinate where I want (i.e at the Left Knee joint).

What is meant by "Orientation" here?
Is it the rotation matrix for rotating along Z axis or something else?

Comment: Generally orientation refers to direction (so, yes, rotation), where as location refers to position (translation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see [Orientation (geometry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28geometry%29). Essentially, it is the rotation relative to a fixed position (zero degrees rotated in every axis). reference would be the pose you must assume when calibrating using [OpenNI](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~grewe/CS6825/Projects/Project3_CPS_KinectCalibration.html) if you choose OpenNI.